# setTimeout animation not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate a square fading into a canvas element. When I use setInterval for my animation, everything works fine, but if I try to use setTimeout, everything falls apart. Here is my code:
http://jsbin.com/OyiRIVa/1/edit

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
/*class canvasUiElement*/
function canvasUiElement() {}
canvasUiElement.prototype = {
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context: canvas.getContext("2d")
}
/* ---------------------*/
function rectangle(x,y,length,width){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.opacity = 0  ;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
rectangle.prototype = new canvasUiElement();
rectangle.prototype.renderSelf = function(){
    this.context.clearRect(this.x,this.y,this.length,this.width);
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,".concat(this.opacity.toString().concat(")"));
    this.context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.length,this.width);
}
rectangle.prototype.drawFrame = function(){
    this.opacity += .01;
    this.renderSelf();
    x = this.drawFrame;
    setTimeout(function(){x()}, 5); 
}
rect = new rectangle(20,10,50,50);
rect.drawFrame();
/*window.setInterval(function() {
    rect.drawFrame();
}, 1); */
```

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout`, use `requestAnimationFrame` (as you already "shim"ed) to better match the browser's redraw cycle.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame doesnt work either :(

Comment: Also: your `x` is a global variable...not good. Instead of creating two anonymous functions, name the first one, and use that. `rectangle.prototype.drawFrame = function() putYourNameHere_drawFrame{`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the `this` keyword in `drawFrame`. When the `setTimeout` fires, `this` in side is no longer `rect`.

The solution is using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
`f.apply(self)` bind the `this` keyword in function `f` to the first argument `f`.

So change this way:

```
rectangle.prototype.drawFrame = function draw(){
  var self = this;
  this.opacity += 0.005;
  this.renderSelf();
  if (this.opacity < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      draw.call(self)
    });
  }
};
```

check out this JSBin. http://jsbin.com/OwaHALUF/4/edit

========================

edited upon a valid comment:

- `x` in the original code is not semantic and misses `var` declaration. Fixed.
- prefer `requestAnimationFrame` to `setTimeout`
- stop call `drawFrame` if opacity >= 1 (useful if requestAnimationFrame is not availlable)
- prefer named function expression over re-assignment. It reduces closure overhead.(This overhead may be not neglected if the animation lasts long enough). And more concise code is bonus.

Comment: `x` is global and not needed: Use a named function instead: http://jsbin.com/OwaHALUF/3/ and please consider using requestAnimationFrame

Comment: You're right. And there are several issues here to be handled. To cancel timer, to detect `raf` feature... But they are too far away from the question (even requiring rewriting whole code).

Comment: I agree that there are multiple things that should be fixed in the original code. However, if you fix the things I suggested in your answer, I will give YOU an upvote :)

Comment: Good that you quit the animation when it was finished. Since you have `self` you could do `self.draw()` instead of `draw.call(self)` (and you could still name the function instead of creating a new variable for it) Anyway, I gave you an upvote.

Comment: I think named function expression indeed is a better solution. It does not require extra declaration and assignment, which yields more compact code and eschews closure overhead. (say, every `raf` call need to look up for `draw` in the previous function). I have to re-edit my answer.